# Interesting if/else if conditional chain problem

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am having a hard time figuring out why this code is working the way it is.  Below, I have all of the code that produces my tic tac toe game.  The game works as intended until we come to a full board that SHOULD result in a win for either `'O'` or `'X'`.  My current logic sometimes will work as intended and pick the correct winner but a majority of the time, it will produce a `'DRAW`', even if the last move on the last square should result in a win.  Given the `if/else if` chain, I don't see how that would work?  The applicable `if/else if` statement is the second set.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let addX = "<h1>X</h1>"
    let addO = "<h1>O</h1>"
    let turn = []
    let board = [$("#one"), $("#two"), $("#three"), $("#four"), $("#five"),$("#six"), $("#seven"), $("#eight"), $("#nine")]
    let combos = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [6,4,2]]
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        board[i].click(function(){
            if (turn.length === 0){
                turn.push(board.indexOf(board[i].html(addX)) + "X")
            } else if (turn.length % 2 !== 0 && board[i].html() === ''){
                turn.push(board.indexOf(board[i].html(addO)) + "O")
            } else if (turn.length % 2 === 0 && board[i].html() === ''){
                turn.push(board.indexOf(board[i].html(addX)) + "X")
            }
            for(let i = 0; i < combos.length; i++){
                if (turn.includes(combos[i][0] + 'O') && turn.includes(combos[i][1] + 'O') && turn.includes(combos[i][2] + 'O') ){
                    alert('O IS WINNER!')
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#ttt_table tbody tr td").html(""); }, 1500);
                    turn.length = 0
                } else if(turn.includes(combos[i][0] + 'X') && turn.includes(combos[i][1] + 'X') && turn.includes(combos[i][2] + 'X') ){
                    alert('X IS WINNER!')
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#ttt_table tbody tr td").html(""); }, 1500);
                    turn.length = 0
                    break
                } else if (turn.length === 9){
                    alert('DRAW!')
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#ttt_table tbody tr td").html(""); }, 1500);
                    turn.length = 0
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Here is a codepen to test out the game itself:

https://codepen.io/tylerp33/pen/NeOxyY

Basically, shouldn't the game see there's a winning combo in:

```
else if(turn.join("").includes(combos[i][0] + 'X') && turn.join("").includes(combos[i][1] + 'X') && turn.join("").includes(combos[i][2] + 'X')
```

before the last

`else if (turn.length === 9)` produces a 'DRAW'?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: With a quick glance it looks like you should break the loop when ever a correct condition is met and handled.

Comment: You've got a `for (let i ...` loop nested inside another one. Because you're using `let` declarations, that will *work*, but inside the inner loop all references to `i` are the one local to that loop, not the outer one.

Comment: You should separate your code into functions. First for must be a function, as well as the second. It will be clearer

Comment: Sorry, but are you saying I can keep it as is, but I need to change the variable name in the second loop?  That didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing or doing much refactoring, adding this to the last condition worked.  Basically, making the if/else run through all the combos before deciding on a draw did the trick.  Thanks for all the help!

```
 else if (turn.length === 9 && combos[i] === combos[combos.length - 1]) {
                    alert('DRAW!')
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#ttt_table tbody tr td").html(""); }, 1500);
                    turn.length = 0
                }
```